# getOffsetRange varibale

Tags: javascript, excel

I have been trying to use a variable as an input in getOffsetRange() property. For example, I have a varianle (say x) which may vary between 1-52 and I want to set the value of a cell at column offset of x from a specified range. Can I pass x as an input in similar to getOffsetRange(0,x)? Does not seem to work. Is there any go around?

I have used a script -

```
let wk=UK_Forecast.getRange("B12").getValue() as Number;
UK_Forecast.getRange("B15").getOffsetRange(0,wk).setValue(hr);
```